# No puedo usar el simulador de ios de xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

He actualizado a `xcode 8`, y mi proyecto a `swift 3`.
El problema es que ahora no puedo utilizar el simulador, solo puedo ejecutar la app en un iphone

La `app` no se llega a lanzar, solo aparece el `Launch.storyboard` y luego se queda la pantalla en negro.

Aqui os pongo el mensaje que aparece en la consola del `xcode`

```
objc[14063]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x118b49910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x118973210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-10-05 09:54:29.339054 Nombre App[14063:72731] bundleid: com.Nombre-App, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:29.340144 Nombre App[14063:72731] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:29.847575 Nombre App[14063:72939] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:29.854779 Nombre App[14063:72939] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:29.950440 Nombre App[14063:72931] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:30.524592 Nombre App[14063:72731] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:30.845837 Nombre App[14063:72731] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCNetworkReachability, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:30.912558 Nombre App[14063:72731] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.095047 Nombre App[14063:72930] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.096243 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 nombre_dominio.esy.es 80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.097054 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.097644 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to nombre_dominio.esy.es:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.098487 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fca28c0fc20
2016-10-05 09:54:31.099088 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.101160 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.102128 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.103415 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.104460 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.105158 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2016-10-05 09:54:31.105851 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: nombre_dominio.esy.es, ifindex: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.107076 Nombre App[14063:72930] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCPreferences, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.109573 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_resolver startWithHandler:] [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting resolver (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.110919 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.123327 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution nombre_dominio.esy.es:80, flags 0x4000d000
2016-10-05 09:54:31.123704 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2016-10-05 09:54:31.124324 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_start_query_timer Starting 1s query timer to receive all address families for nombre_dominio.esy.es:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.124836 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is in_progress
2016-10-05 09:54:31.125280 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is ()
2016-10-05 09:54:31.160727 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=85.21.155.24:0 ttl=21680
2016-10-05 09:54:31.161807 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_cancel_query_timer Cancelling query timer for nombre_dominio.esy.es
2016-10-05 09:54:31.162339 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is complete
2016-10-05 09:54:31.163207 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.163720 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is (85.21.155.24:80)
2016-10-05 09:54:31.164086 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.164429 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.164864 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-05 09:54:31.166055 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 250ms
2016-10-05 09:54:31.166776 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.167435 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.167902 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.169052 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.169503 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.170088 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.170512 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: <nil>, ifindex: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.171537 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.172083 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] creating socket
2016-10-05 09:54:31.172771 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.192506 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2016-10-05 09:54:31.193537 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2016-10-05 09:54:31.194657 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ca6380e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd40194 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3002
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1ddb8 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1cdd5 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1bb34 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd36d11 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd36740 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd4e003 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000
2016-10-05 09:54:31.195708 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached flow protocol
2016-10-05 09:54:31.196142 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.196953 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2016-10-05 09:54:31.280106 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x800
2016-10-05 09:54:31.280867 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received CONNECTED event
2016-10-05 09:54:31.281427 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_socket_setup_notsent_lowat Set TCP_NOTSENT_LOWAT(16384)
2016-10-05 09:54:31.282310 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2016-10-05 09:54:31.283240 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.283648 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.283869 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.284159 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2016-10-05 09:54:31.284418 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2016-10-05 09:54:31.285091 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.285606 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 85.21.155.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2016-10-05 09:54:31.286051 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2016-10-05 09:54:31.286584 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 1 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED in response to state ready and error (null)
2016-10-05 09:54:31.286904 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 1 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED, reason: nw_connection event, should deliver: true
2016-10-05 09:54:31.287734 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 54ms/63ms since start, TCP: 88ms/183ms since start, TLS: 0ms/0ms since start
http://nombre_dominio.esy.es/app/1/json/comercios_1.json
2016-10-05 09:54:31.567048 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 2 nombre_dominio.esy.es 80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.573240 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] tcp_connection_start 2 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.580190 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to nombre_dominio.esy.es:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.661668 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fca28d02010
2016-10-05 09:54:31.662878 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 2 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.664094 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.665525 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 3 nombre_dominio.esy.es 80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.667055 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.668182 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] tcp_connection_start 3 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.669690 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.670435 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to nombre_dominio.esy.es:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.671590 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.672038 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fca28d1f820
2016-10-05 09:54:31.672474 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2016-10-05 09:54:31.672908 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: nombre_dominio.esy.es, ifindex: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.673709 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_resolver startWithHandler:] [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting resolver (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.674035 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.674568 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution nombre_dominio.esy.es:80, flags 0x4000d000
2016-10-05 09:54:31.675836 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 3 starting
2016-10-05 09:54:31.676535 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2016-10-05 09:54:31.677214 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.678150 Nombre App[14063:72951] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=85.21.155.24:0 ttl=21680
2016-10-05 09:54:31.679305 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.680398 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.681842 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.682847 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2016-10-05 09:54:31.684482 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: nombre_dominio.esy.es, ifindex: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.687213 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_resolver startWithHandler:] [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 waiting resolver (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.687967 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.688890 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution nombre_dominio.esy.es:80, flags 0x4000d000
2016-10-05 09:54:31.689543 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2016-10-05 09:54:31.689976 Nombre App[14063:72930] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=nombre_dominio.esy.es. addr=85.21.155.24:0 ttl=21680
2016-10-05 09:54:31.690425 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is complete
2016-10-05 09:54:31.690698 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.691386 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is (85.21.155.24:80)
2016-10-05 09:54:31.691630 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.691902 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] resolver is complete
2016-10-05 09:54:31.692143 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding endpoint handler for 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.692391 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated endpoint list is (85.21.155.24:80)
2016-10-05 09:54:31.693056 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:receive_dns
2016-10-05 09:54:31.693474 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.693964 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-05 09:54:31.694751 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 250ms
2016-10-05 09:54:31.695169 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.695635 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[2.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.696195 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.696810 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.697217 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[2.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.697496 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.697752 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: <nil>, ifindex: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.699417 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.722092 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] creating socket
2016-10-05 09:54:31.722702 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.723164 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2016-10-05 09:54:31.723719 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ca6380e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd40194 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3002
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1ddb8 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1cdd5 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd1bb34 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd36d11 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd36740 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010cd4e003 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000
2016-10-05 09:54:31.740077 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached flow protocol
2016-10-05 09:54:31.740854 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [2 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[2.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.741670 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2.1 85.21.155.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2016-10-05 09:54:31.742815 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint 85.21.155.24:80
2016-10-05 09:54:31.743901 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-05 09:54:31.745164 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in 250ms
2016-10-05 09:54:31.746785 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [3.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.748151 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[3.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.749090 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3.1 85.21.155.24:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-10-05 09:54:31.770875 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [3.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.779169 Nombre App[14063:72731] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.780107 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [3 nombre_dominio.esy.es:80 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[3.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-10-05 09:54:31.784303 Nombre App[14063:72931] subsystem: com.apple.locationd.Motion, category: Calorimetry, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 1, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.784679 Nombre App[14063:72931] subsystem: com.apple.locationd.Motion, category: Swimming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 1, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.785615 Nombre App[14063:72931] subsystem: com.apple.locationd.Motion, category: Activity, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 1, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.786134 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [3.1 85.21.155.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2016-10-05 09:54:31.786606 Nombre App[14063:72931] subsystem: com.apple.locationd.Motion, category: Motion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 1, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-05 09:54:31.789565 Nombre App[14063:72933] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: <nil>, ifindex: 0
```

El mensaje que aparece es mucho mas largo pero supera el limite de caracteres en una pregunta

Comment: Tenes bien configurado el Initial View Controller, y la vista inicial conectada a un controller?

Comment: has visto esta pregunta en ingles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491675/runtime-issues-with-ios-10-xcode-8

Comment: Te has bajado los simuladores?

Comment: Solo he actualizado el xcode, por lo que los simuladores ya estaban @Spidvmp

Comment: Yo la verdad eliminaria los simuladores y los volvería a cargar. No se como van las tripas de esto, pero imagino los los simuladores de xcode7.3.1 no soportan swift3. Aquí hay una en ingles de como eliminar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834817/xcode-simulator-how-to-remove-older-unneeded-devices.

Comment: Y otro proyecto, un Hello world, con el simulador y Xcode 8, te funciona? así descartarlas que el problema esta en la app tuya o en Xcode/simuladores

Comment: He probado un hello world y funciona, por lo que le problema esta en mi proyecto. Gracias @Spidvmp

Answer (score 1):

El error dice:

> objc[14063]: Class **PLBuildVersion** is implemented in both:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/**AssetsLibraryServices**
> (0x118b49910)

and

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/**PhotoLibraryServices**
> (0x118973210).
>
> **One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Revisa en la ruta principal del proyecto, viñeta **"Build phases" -> "Link binary library"** es probable que el emulador tenga pre-cargada una librería que ya no utilizas en el proyecto.

Prueba también eliminando los datos del emulador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]